# How to automatically synchronize in Android

Tags: android, performance

I read about how to be notified when there is connection, so I made a listener to it.
But to make an auto-synchronizer data, I need to make a listener for when the device is started?

If yes, what the OnBootListener will do? Nothing?

This is the right way?

Comment: Why not synchronize only when your application has started?

Comment: and if the application does not start after reboot? user can wait to be notified, but that will never happen, right?

Comment: no, why should any application synchronize data on reboot, if the application might not even start? If the application won't even start on a device boot, then it doesn't need the data, does it?

Comment: For example, a schedule of events. After booting, I check the server for new events, so I put an icon in the notification area. I wonder if this is the correct approach.